# Executing a python script from image source in html

Tags: python, html, apache, cgi-bin

I am sending an email from my local machine via python using gmail smtp server.
I have embedded an html in the body which has an image whose source is in some remote ec2 server which is a python file.

The code looks like below:

```
def getHtml(body):
        html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <div style='background-color: rgb(255,67,0); font-family: helvetica;padding:5px;color:#fff;'>google
     </div><br/>
        <img border="0" src="http://xyz.com:8000/poc.py">
        """+body+"""
     <br/><br/>
     <a title="launch button" href="http://google.com" style="font-size:15px;line-height:1.3;font-family:arial,sans-serif" target="_blank">Launch Now</a>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <br/>
         - hi
         <br/>
         <br/>
 </body>
</html>
"""
        return html

def sendMail():
        subject = "POC"
        bodyContent="body"
        bodyText = bodyContent
        me = "x@gmail.com"
        to = "x@gmail.com"
        email_input = "jx@gmail.com"
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg["From"] = me
        msg["To"] = me
        msg["Subject"] = subject
        part1 = MIMEText(bodyText, 'plain')
        part2 = MIMEText(getHtml(bodyText), 'html')
        msg.attach(part1)
        msg.attach(part2)
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.login('x@gmail.com', 'passwd')
        s.sendmail(me, [to,email_input], msg.as_string())




sendMail()
```

in xyz.com i have started a simplehttpserver using python -m simplehttpserver in the folder where poc.py is present.

poc.py looks like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

f = open('workfile', 'w')
f.close()

filename="th_goldhill.png"
sys.stdout.write( "Content-type: image/png\r\n\r\n" + file(filename,"rb").read() )
```

Now this file is not getting created in the server.
when i open the email i see this on server "[28/May/2013 11:28:46] "GET /poc.py HTTP/1.1" 200 " that means the request is coming to server.

Comment: `SimpleHTTPServer` won't execute Python scripts. Take a look at [`CGIHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html).

Comment: @Aya   python -m CGIHTTPServer i started this instead of simplehttpserver but still it does not execute

Comment: By default, the server will only execute scripts if they're in a subdirectory called `cgi-bin`, so you'll have to move it, then reference it as `http://xyz.com:8000/cgi-bin/poc.py`.

Comment: Thanks Aya , it worked , one more question i had was can i also pass some arguments in to the src like 
http://localhost:8080/xyz.py?name=sas&city=ny and read these params inside the python file . This is important for me

Comment: Yep. I think you can pull that out of `os.environ['QUERY_STRING']`